# Rails Error In Production, may due to link_tag and precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I have installed `rails 3.1` with `apache2` and `passenger` on `ubuntu 10.04`. using `ruby 1.9.2` with `RVM`. 
When I load the application in browser in production (development version works fine on my machine), it does not work.

My Production Error Log is:

```
Started GET "/articles" for 117.230.75.50 at 2011-09-12 13:51:34 +0000
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (56.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 126ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Youexpress</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__385712067674585148_29380260'
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

But, when I remove the link_tags in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb like this, the application works fine in production mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Youexpress</title>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get Around this? When I do `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- uglifier
  (in /home/username/youexpress/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js)
```

Note: In the above error it shows ruby/1.9.1 not 1.9.2 ( I've installed 1.9.2 )

Please help with my situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer myself, The reason for the error is rails app needs javascript runtime for certain features of sass, coffeescript and uglifier to work.

There are many ways to solve this, by installing javascript runtimes like `nodejs`

But, the solution I went with, and perhaps the easiest one is, adding `gem 'therubyracer'` to my `Gemfile` and then running `bundle install`

Excerpt from my `Gemfile` is below

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

adding `therubyracer` also fixes `rake assets:precompile`

Hope this helps. I've spent days searching for this solution.