# Rails ActionView Template Error No Such File to Load (SASS) on Production Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jdbc, sass, libv8

I'm trying to launch my Rails app in Production but it doesn't work and fails to launch with the following error (it runs fine in Development):

```
ActionView::Template::Eror (no such file to load -- sass in (/.../app/assets/stylesheets/file.css.scss)):

13: ...
14: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media => "all" %>
15: ...

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb: 14:in '_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb'
```

I looked at this StackOverflow post: [Rails Error In Production, may due to link_tag and precompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390049/rails-error-in-production-may-due-to-link-tag-and-precompilation) and tried installing the gem 'therubyracer' but once I do that and try to bundle install, it fails while trying to install the gem libv8 `(An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and bundler cannot continue)`.

Relevant parts of my Gemfile if it helps:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', "1.2.2"
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '1.2.1'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'less-rails', '2.3.3'
gem 'rubyzip', '0.9.9'
```

The production part of my config/database.yml file (I'm using PostgreSQL, don't know if that's relevant):

```
production:
  adapter: jdbc
  jndi: jdbc/appname
  database: appname
  user: appname
  password: appname
  host: <ip address>
```

I'm very confused about how to proceed and any help would be appreciated.

Note: I create a .war file using warbler and then try to launch it via GlassFish

Edit: My application.css file is:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 *= require bootstrap-select.min
 */
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `application.css` file in the question.

Comment: Absolutely, I added it to the original question

Comment: Do you have a file named `file.css.scc` within `app/assets/stylesheets` folder? Also the extension should be `.scss` and not `.scc`.

Comment: Yes I do, but that file is entirely blank. All it contains is this `// Place all the styles related to the admin controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/`

Comment: And the extension of the file is `.scss`?

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo in my question.